# I can not install npm to use laravel mix

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, laravel-mix

I'm following a tutorial where they use laravel mix, and for that I must install node.js and then installi npm. But the problem is that when I execute the command `npm install`, the console returns the following errors:

[image]

What could be the problem?

[VIEW IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4VHq.png)

Comment: Those are not errors, they are warnings. For tutorial purposes you can ignore these

Comment: Thanks, but when i run *npm run dev* it shows me the following errors. What can be? (I just added a photo to the publication) @milk

Comment: Post contents of `events.js`. There is an error that can be thrown on line 183 which is not being handled. You can try wrapping the throw er line in a `try/catch` block

Answer (score 2):

Delete **node_modules** folder and run `npm install` again. Most times this fixes the issue